# How's it going at school? / How are you doing at school?

Tags: questions, idiomatic-language

Let's say I'm with my sister and her two kids (aged 6 and 8). How do I ask the kids about school?

Would "How's it going at school?" be perfectly natural? And "How are you doing at school?" as well?

Is there one standard way to ask this?

Also, if I don't want my question to focus too much on grades, what would be the most natural thing ask?

Thank you.

Comment: I would just ask “how’s school?”. The intention behind it is pretty obvious.

Comment: Thanks. Would "How's it going at school?" and "How are you doing at school?" be natural as well?

Comment: Yes, they would. "How's it going?" asks about things in general, "How are you doing?" might be understood as a question about their progress in lessons.